# Where can I find indie "teams"

Tags: project-management

I'm looking to work over the internet in a team of people to make a game. I'm not looking to make a profit, I just want the experiance. Where can I find similary minded persons?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally I don't like working with random people over the internet. Also you will find few games actually succeed without the dynamic of loyalty and accountability that comes with actually having to deal with someone.

If you are a student ask around, I promise there are others interested in the same things as you. If not Google around and try to find a game development meet up in your area. Also there are often groups dedicated to certain technologies (XNA, Unity) if you live in a populate enough area.

If that fails I suggest looking at currently under development opensource games and seeing if they will let you join. Forking it and making a meaning full improvement or fix is a great way to get a team to enthusiastically welcome you.

But just speaking from experience, its near impossible to get any sort of dedication or staying power for a project unless the members and invested in it and each other emotionally.

Anyways that is my 2c. Mostly coming from experience founding modding teams.

Comment: +1 for finding people in person. Check if your local IGDA chapter has any meetups. Or if you have any other similar organization. For example, NYC has NYCGI and Philadelphia has VGI Philly. Find out if there's going to be a Global Game Jam site in your area.

Comment: People on the internet usually also have vastly different views on 'religious' topics - very often views of people will align over time; if they know each other in person. It's difficult making a game when everyone wants to do it differently.

Comment: I disagree, I've worked on several mod teams and never had an issue; most of the time they haven't even been local, I've worked across time differences of 12 hours and still had cohesive work flow.
It all depends on the who, and what their motivations are. IMHO these projects don't work unless everyone gets an input. No one wants to be a slave worker; and in most cases, most of the developers aren't unintelligent.

Comment: addition to @Daniel, that's how i got started too and didn't have any issue. The only issue you have is an asynchronous workflow and hard to meet release dates.

Answer (score 3):

[IndieDB](http://www.indiedb.com/) is a good place for indie develoers. They even have a dedicated [job section](http://www.indiedb.com/jobs). Paid and unpaid.

For beginners, its easier to start with modding, ModDB. Pick a game your like to mod. Then look for existing mods and see if they need someone of your skill. i.e. Half Life 2.

Also, note what @ClassicThunder said. You said you only want the experience. So, for *ONLY* experience both of them are a very good place to start. But, very few of them actually get completed. So, prepare for anything!

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend going to game jams, where people attempt to make video games in a short time span.  If you are looking for experience in working with others, they are great environments to do so.

I recommend the [Global Game Jam](http://globalgamejam.org/), but there are many others.  A place to look for them is [CompoHub](http://compohub.net/) which is mainly online game jams/contests but also lists local ones as well. Some places have much more of a game development scene than others.