# Starting a game project

Tags: project-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find indie “teams”](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/19847/where-can-i-find-indie-teams)

I already know this is probably not the right place to ask and, if you think this question does not belong here, please delete it. So, the question is,

If I decided to start a video game project, is there a place where I can sort of "recruit" people who might want to join me and develop the game together?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you have no actual working game at all yet, then you are looking for recruitment at the wrong time.

If you want people to join up, you need something up and running.  You need a basic proof of concept.  You need to show that you can get stuff done.  You need to show that you are serious.  You need to be able to catch their interest.

Absolutely nobody is interested in joining your team (presumably with you as a leader) if you have zero anything to show off.  You have no way to actually get people interested if you have nothing to show them.  There are a million and six joes going around saying "I have an idea please help me make it come to life."  There are very few people who can say "look here at this awesome prototype I made that you can play right now and see how awesome it is first hand, so who wants to help make it more awesome?"

It doesn't matter much if what you can build is not polished.  Nobody is going to expect you to have any kind of real art, nor to have a production-quality game engine, nor even a final version of the core game mechanics prototyped.  If you saw what prototypes of your favorite AAA games looked like when they were pitched to publishers, you'd laugh quite hard; they look like crap, hardly look like a game at all, and certainly look like nothing even remotely close to the final product.  However, they are still playable, interactive, and show off the core elements of the game, at least enough so that people can make an educated judgment about whether the game will be fun or interesting.

If you're not in a position to even make a basic prototype in Unity or something, you're not at a point where you should be looking for teammates.  If you can't do even the simplest of things on your own, you need to improve your own skills, not drag down a team of people with your lack of skills.  Make some small, simple practice games on your own, get some experience, and build up your skillset first.  Then join another existing team as a junior member rather than trying to start and lead your own team, so that you can build your team skills and slowly work up to leadership skills.  Only once you've got a solid foundation of game development/production skills and a solid foundation of teamwork/leadership skills do you have business trying to form a new team.  Not saying that to be mean, but rather just to save you from a lot of potential grief.

Comment: Yea, totally understand that. I'm just new to game development but forgot to mention that I already got a prototype started. But yes, you are right. Better wait to have something more "solid". Thank you.